# Attaching popup to bottom of a div

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to have a clickable div so that when its clicked it appends to the bottom of the div that is clicked.  I have it so when i click it appears where the mouse is but i want it to be right below the div that is clicked and is right up against the bottom border.

I tried using $(div).position.left(); but it wasnt placing it in the right place and changed when you resized the screen.

Any idea on how to do what I am looking for?

Thanks,

Craig

**Here is the code**

```
$('#clickDetails').click(function(e) {
$('#dcHover')
.css('position', 'absolute')
.css('top', e.pageY + 10)
.css('left', e.pageX - 8)
.css('z-index','2')
.toggle();
//$('#clickDetails').append('<div id="dchover">test</div>');
});
```

ANd this is the div tag

```
<div id="clickDetails" style=" width: 10px; background-color:red; padding: 1px 5px 1px 5px; color: white; -moz-border-radius:5px; margin-top:-80px; margin-right:35px; z-index: -1;">!</div>
```

Comment: Please append your code so we can have a better look ;-).

Comment: For the div you are trying to position, did you make sure to mark it as absolutely positioned? `position:fixed;`   Maybe you could do a mockup on http://jsfiddle.net so we can see your work so far and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the .after() function in Jquery

HTML:

```
<div id="div1" class="d">Click Me</div>
<div id="div3" class="d">Click Me</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".d").click(function(){
    $(this).after("<div id='div2'>Appended</div>");
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PeepD/1/

Answer (score 0):

You are applying CSS styles before the element has been appended, therefore they're not being added to `dchover`

Try rearranging your code like this:

```
$('#clickDetails').click(function(e) {
$('#clickDetails').append('<div id="dchover">test</div>');
$('#dchover')
.css('position', 'absolute')
.css('top', e.pageY + 10)
.css('left', e.pageX - 8)
.css('z-index','2')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you actually want to append a new div after the current div.

To do so, use the jQuery [after](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http://api.jquery.com/after/&ei=xPiBTqzTHMnJ0QWPs4HMAQ&usg=AFQjCNGeLGXIPQ355EEKquFXrzYr4KZSmQ&sig2=HDTj4I7klASNeb_LGI_lkQ) method.

```
$(function(){

    // handle the click event of the div with id 'clickme'
    $("#clickme").click(function(){

        // this is now the div that has been clicked
        $(this).after("<div class='added'>testing</div>");

    });

});
```

Then use CSS to reduce or increase the margin between the divs as you require.

Check it out here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ajbyt/3/